# Unable to parse JSON response from jquery Ajax Call

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm relatively new to jquery/ajax, and I'm having trouble parsing the results from a very simple JSON ajax call.  Here's my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/A7uqB/6/).  There are 2 test URLs in this example: the commented URL works as expected, but the uncommented URL does not (they are both properly formatted JSON, according to jslint). Any idea why one would throw a parse error, and the other would not (they are both 3rd party domains)?

Thank you in advance!

```
function getNews2() {

$.ajax({

    //url: "http://api.ihackernews.com/page?format=jsonp",
    url: "http://recs.coremetrics.com/iorequest/restapi?cm_cid=90232642&cm_zoneid=Mobile&cm_targetid=FULO-0101",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        alert("SUCCESS recsStatus=" + textStatus);
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function(data, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("FAILURE recsStatus=" + textStatus);
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});
}

getNews2();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after looking at responses from both URLs with CURL, the one that doesn't work is not a jsonp response.  It's  a json response.  It's not wrapped in the method call required by json p to work.

The one that doesn't work is

`{"io":{"rec_count":12,...}}`

vs

`HNCallback({"nextId":null,...})`

see the difference?

You won't be able to get a pure json response from either URL because of the same origin policy.  So you need to use CORS (if you control the other domains), or jsonp, like you are currently configured to use, or server side proxy.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Excuse my ignorance, but isn't there a way to convert the json (from the network request) to a properly formatted jsonp response? I thought that "dataType (json jsonp);" would do this, or possible use of the dataFilter option?

Comment: no.  you can't even get the json data because of the same origin policy.

Comment: So if the result is not JSONP for cross-domain requests, it's not possible...thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Ok, so I'm now trying to work within the bounds of the browser restrictions, and I've taken my JSON response, saved it as a JSONP file on a 3rd party site (with the callback function added), and it's still not working.  The original Fiddler was just updated with my slight change (which purely changed the URL to point to the JSONP file).  If the response is JSONP, why wouldn't this work like the working URL (is it because it's a file resource rather than a web service?)?

Comment: the browser wont make the request.  read about the same origin policy

Comment: What I've done is taken the text feed (remember: the response is in JSON format, not JSONP, and the response Content-Type header is text), and pushed it through Yahoo Pipes, which now returns a valid JSONP response (with the required callback function, and a response Content-Type header of "application/json; charset=utf-8").  I still get the parseError, but the data.responseText for the error is the JSON that I want to grab!!  It seems like the data is being received now, but it just can't be parsed.  Any idea why it can't be parsed?  My new [code](http://jsfiddle.net/A7uqB/10/).

Comment: Ah!  I see...I was missing the callback.  Thank you so much for your assistance, and more importantly, your patience (both are very much appreciated!!)